# GDAL Georeferencer Tool Not Appearing In Processing Menu - QGIS 3.4 Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, ubuntu

I know this question has been raised several times before ([Georeferencer on QGIS3 Missing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274499/georeferencer-on-qgis3-missing) and [Missing Georeferencer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87009/missing-georeferencer)), but my situation is somewhat different. The georeferencer tool does not appear in the processing menu, and I have tried checking the box under the plugin settings - it will stay checked while in same session, but if I close QGIS and restart, the box is unchecked again. Either way, the tool never appears in the processing menu. I have also uninstalled/reinstalled QGIS and find the exact same situation.

Comment: do you have multiple versions of QGIS installed? If you uncheck georeferencer in one of them, it might uncheck them in both. Its a weird interaction.

Comment: Please provide links to where this has been asked before so that potential answerers do not need to volunteer time trying to find them before deciding whether your question is new or a duplicate

Comment: No multiple versions, but I did briefly try 3.10 and uninstalled it to go back to 3.4. I suspect that could be the problem but have no idea how to go about correcting it. I purged the newer version of gdal, however, when I uninstalled 3.10.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide clarifications. It's not fair to those who might try to help to force them to scour the comments looking for critical information.

Comment: Have you checked from the Raster menu?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the raster menu, and used the toolbox search bar to cover all bases regarding the location of the tool.